# How to handle apostophes in user inputted String?

Tags: java, sql, validation, error-handling, user-input

So I'm making a program that takes user input from a GUI as a parameter. How do I handle it if the user inputs a word or sentence with an apostrophe?

I'm using it to input something into a database, so for example:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('"+firstNameString+"', '"+lastNameString+"')
```

If the user's name was something like John O'Neill, this would throw an error. 
How do I handle that apostrope, given that I can't control what users may input?

Comment: Use prepared statement.

Comment: use prepared statements

Comment: use prepared statements- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: use prepared statements - otherwise your code will be prone for SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid problems like this use PreparedStatements. Typically your code will look something like this:

```
....
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?,?)");
ps.setString(1,firstNameString);
ps.setString(2,lastNameString);
int result = ps.executeUpdate();
...
```

Comment: Okay, and this will just handle any apostrophes that might be in the inputted text?

Comment: It will handle it for you, yes.

Answer (score -1):

To add escape sequence you can use `'` in Oracle, If you want to escape `'` then add `'''`

First `'` is the starting of String
Second `'` escapes third char in our case that is `'`

Comment: While technically correct, this approach is a bad idea.  Query parameters are a better approach.  Hence the downvote.

Comment: Yes, I agree but i just wanted to say an option to escape `'` character